# Fixing a Query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to display the code of the Department in the School table with the highest total Salary of any department.

So I tried this:

```
SELECT MAX(Total), dept 

FROM (SELECT SUM(salary) AS Total, dept from school group by dept) AS Temp;
```

Which gives me the correct result; however it shows the field MAX(Total) and I just want the code of the department to show. What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT a.dept FROM (
    SELECT MAX(Total), dept 

    FROM (SELECT SUM(salary) AS Total, dept from school group by dept) AS Temp
) AS a;
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

If you need department code with max salary fund:

```
SELECT a.dept 
FROM (SELECT SUM(salary) AS Total, dept from school group by dept) AS a
ORDER BY a.Total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```